# ů ř do not appear in the listings

Tags: listings

How to include ů and ř to the listings, please?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myscript.txt}
script.txt
# hello
í ů ř á
hello
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[%
  auto counter,%
  list inside=lol,%
  list type={lstlisting}%
  ]%
  {\mylisting}%
  [2]{%
  listing file={#1},%
  title=Listing,%
  colback=white,%
  colframe=gray!75!black,%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,%
  listing only,%
  breakable,%
  title={Script \thetcbcounter: #2},%
}

\begin{document}
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,%
  commentstyle=\color{purple},% Not working :(
  morecomment=[l]{\#}%
}

\mylisting{myscript.txt}{My script}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: well, you can just use `xelatex` or `lualatex` to compile your file to let them appear

Answer (score 7):

You need `literate`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.txt}
script.txt
# hello
í ů ř á
hello
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[
  auto counter,
  list inside=lol,
  list type={lstlisting}
]{\mylisting}[2]{
  listing file={#1},
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  title={Script \thetcbcounter: #2},
}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{purple},
  morecomment=[l]{\#},
  literate=
   {í}{{\'i}}1
   {ů}{{\r{u}}}1
   {ř}{{\v{r}}}1
   {á}{{\'a}}1
   % add the other needed characters along the same line
}

\begin{document}

\mylisting{\jobname.txt}{My script}

\end{document}
```

Be sure to input the characters as single Unicode points, not with combining accents.

[image]

You might try with this: the problem with your setting might be that your editor uses combining accents without normalization.

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{purple},
  morecomment=[l]{\#},
  literate=
   {í}{{\'i}}1
   {ů}{{\r{u}}}1 % U+016F
   {u^^cc^^8a}{{\r{u}}}1
   {ř}{{\v{r}}}1 % U+0159
   {r^^cc^^8c}{{\v{r}}}1
   {á}{{\'a}}1
   % add the other needed characters along the same line
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got the same output. What do you mean by 'Be sure to input the characters as single Unicode points, not with combining accents', please??

Comment: @Anna-Kat I guess it depends on the editor you're using. In Unicode, ř can be input as U+0159 or with the combination U+0072 (r) followed by U+030C (combining caron). With `pdflatex` only the first can be used.

Comment: How to set that? I just press ř on the keyboard to write it in a .txt file.

Comment: @Anna-Kat I don't really know what's your setup, it's not really possible to help without greater details.

Comment: When I copy your code, I obtain the same output as before.

Comment: @Anna-Kat I added some alternatives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131968/discussion-between-anna-kat-and-egreg).

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use `lualatex` and then the problems go away.

But if you have to stick to `pdflatex` then you could use the `listingsutf8` `tcolorbox` library and specify an appropriate encoding (`latin2`).

Use `listings options={}` in the options of your `tcolorbox` rather than `\lstset` which seems to be ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myscript.txt}
script.txt
# hello
í ů ř á
hello
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}
\newtcbinputlisting{\mylisting}[1]{
  listing utf8=latin2,
  listing file={#1},
  listing only,
  listing options={
    style=tcblatex,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{purple},
    morecomment={[l]{\#}}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\mylisting{myscript.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]